# PHP Array: Populate a range of repeats

Tags: php, arrays

Big picture: I'm needing to process data to find which combinations of the data (including repeats up to 4) meet criteria best.

From a basic array (1,2,3) and a $repeat_max=4 variable, I'm wanting to create an array like this programmatically since the array values will be dynamic. Please forgive any minor syntax errors, this is just a general concept.  Please tell me if this is the worst idea ever.  How do i loop through $data and create $indiv?

```
$data = array(1,2,3);

$indiv[0] => array ([0] => array([0] = 1),
                    [1] => array([0] = 1, [1] = 1),
                    [2] => array([0] = 1, [1] = 1, [2] = 1),
                    [3] => array([0] = 1, [1] = 1, [2] = 1, [3] = 1)),
$indiv[1] => array ([0] => array([0] = 2),
                    [1] => array([0] = 2, [1] = 2),
                    [2] => array([0] = 2, [1] = 2, [2] = 2),
                    [3] => array([0] = 2, [1] = 2, [2] = 2, [3] = 2)),
$indiv[2] => array ([0] => array([0] = 3),
                    [1] => array([0] = 3, [1] = 3),
                    [2] => array([0] = 3, [1] = 3, [2] = 3),
                    [3] => array([0] = 3, [1] = 3, [2] = 3, [3] = 3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`array_fill`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) should do the trick:

```
$indiv = array();
foreach ($data as $val) {
  $tmp = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < $repeat_max; $i++) $tmp[$i] = array_fill(0, $i + 1, $val);
  $indiv[] = $tmp;
}
```

With `$data = [ 1, 2 ]` and `$repeat_max = 3` it looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 2
                )

        )

)
```